# Function from space of continuous functions to reals is continuous (Proof Verification)

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, continuity

Question:

$C$ is the space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ under the sup metric. Prove the function 
$$f:C\to\mathbb{R}\quad f\to \int_0^1 f(t)^2 dt$$
is continuous.

My answer:

Continuity means:

$$\forall \epsilon >0 \quad \exists \delta >0 \quad st \quad \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)| < \delta \implies \left|\int_0^1 f(t)^2dt - \int_0^1 g(t)^2dt  \right|< \epsilon$$

But $f,g$ are continuous functions on a $[0,1]$ which is closed so $f,g$ are bounded on $[0,1]$.

$$\left|\int_0^1 f(t)dt - \int_0^1 g(t)dt \right|  \leq \int_0^1 |f(t)-g(t)||f(t)+g(t)|dt \leq M\int_0^1 |f(t)-g(t)| dt$$
$$ \leq M \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)| \leq M\delta$$

Where $$ M = \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)+g(x)|$$

So let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{M}$.

Does this make sense?

EDIT:-------------------------------

$$M = \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)+g(x)| \leq 2|\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)| + \delta $$

Comment: I guess you felt that something is not quite right with $M$. Your continuity as phrased is actually "uniform continuity". I think you should rather prove something like: $\forall f$ $\forall \epsilon$ $\exists \delta$ s.t. $\forall g$ with .....

Comment: Your $\delta$ can't depend on $g$. Try to change $M$ to something that depends on $f$ only.

Comment: @QiyuWen Can you give me a reason why $\delta$ can depend on $f$ but not on $g$?

Comment: Your $g$ is close to $f$.

Comment: @QiyuWen I tried something but I it's wrong because it's circular dependent but I don't really know how to continue otherwise.

Comment: $|f + g| \leq 2|f| + \delta$.